# NSUserDefaults not saved after synchronize

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have the following code in my app

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:kArchivedUsername forKey:userID];
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"saved: %@", [defaults stringForKey:kArchivedUsername]);
```

However, the output is this:

```
2016-04-07 15:50:44.560 BP (Test)[18357:464518] saved: (null)
```

Can anybody tell me why and what I can do about this?

Comment: y r u looking for key kArchivedUsername ? Aren't u suppose to look for key userID?

Comment: Note that `synchronize` is doing absolutely nothing useful here except slowing down your program. It's finally slated for deprecation because of all the misunderstandings around it. Useful discussion from the maintainer of `NSUserDefaults`: http://dscoder.com/defaults.html

Comment: Ohh man, you are using a value as a key...!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have key and value reversed:

```
[defaults setObject:userID forKey:kArchivedUsername];
```

Credit to: Teja Nandamuri

Answer (score 4):

Here is your code

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:kArchivedUsername forKey:userID];
[defaults synchronize];
NSLog(@"saved: %@", [defaults stringForKey:kArchivedUsername]);
```

See how you specify the key in 2 places `forKey:userID` vs `stringForKey:kArchivedUsername`

It's better to double check it

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Simple One**

```
//NSUserDefault For Save:-

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:usernamestr1 forKey:@"Usernamestr1"];
```

// For Fatch :-

```
 Cathing_Name_str3 =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Usernamestr1"];
```

Comment: please always post answer, instead try to editing original question with your suggestion, your edit will be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

```
[defaults stringForKey:kArchivedUsername] 

In this line pass your Key instead of Value like. Please follow below code.

[defaults stringForKey:userID] 
o/p 2016-04-07 23:13:08.723 segmentTintColor[27646:662430] saved: kArchivedUsername
```